# Is the HTTP_HOST server variable always defined?

Tags: php, apache, iis

Is the server variable `HTTP_HOST` always defined for all servers, or for example in IIS is defined with other name or even is not defined at all?

Also, that value is always defined? Or some host they don't define that value? Is there any other way to retrieve that value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting the manual

HTTP_HOST is

```
Contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one.
```

HTTP_HOST is a part of the client's HTTP request and specifies which host name the request is to be directed to. if HTTP_HOST is not set, the client is either very, very old (HTTP 1.0 doesn't support HTTP_HOST) or has made a request directly to your web site's IP.

I think the Host HTTP Header is mandatory since HTTP 1.1

Comment: Do you beleave in most case the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] will work ? Because I create a script to be shared as a free resources and will be installed in many diferent servers

Comment: You rock ... seriously I couldn't find a simple answer like this anywhere. What do you suggest to read in order to understand the anatomy of http-requests/headers ... etc?

Comment: "**or** has made a request directly to your web site's IP" - This doesn't necessarily mean the `Host:` header is not set - it could simply be set to the IP address.

Answer (score 2):

`HTTP_HOST` is not defined by server, it's

> Contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is
>   one.

So it depends on whether the header info of your request contain `Host`.

Comment: So the next question, is a way to obtain always a value indentical to HTTP_HOST ?

Comment: On IIS you can use SERVER_NAME as a fallback. On Apache the same variable may or may not be available (see [`ServerName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#servername) directive in httpd.conf).

Answer (score 1):

It is not always defined.

As quoted above, it is only defined if there is a http request. If you are running the php script from CLI (e.g php filename.php) the `HTTP_HOST` key will not be set.

Moreover, you should note that `HTTP_HOST` is defined by the client, so it is pretty much easy to fake it and it is not reliable. You should rather rely on something like `SERVER_NAME`.

If you are using PHP >= 5.3.0 then you should use

```
gethostname();
```

You may check [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php) for the documentation.

If you are using PHP >= 4.2.0 & PHP < 5.3.0 then

```
php_uname('n');
```

will do the same work.

Comment: `gethostname()` returns the "host name for the local machine" which isn't necessarily the same thing that would otherwise be returned from `HTTP_HOST` - especially if the same machine is serving more than one site. "`get_uname('n')`" should be `php_uname('n')`.