# Artisan stopped working on XAMPP?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laravel-artisan

My php artisan commands doesn't work anymore. It says something like this:

```
php artisan   [ErrorException]   Undefined index: HTTP_HOST
```

I have the latest version of XAMPP on a Windows 8 machine.

What's going on?

Comment: is it not working on single project or all projects?

Comment: When artisan returns an error message it doesn't mean it's an specific artisan error: It just means that you have some error in your application, and artisan kinda "refuses" working on a buggy application. So, review your more recent changes in your code.

Comment: @Amarnasan lol, therefore I ask if it is only one project or all project, to find out if it is XAMPP problem thing or specific application? it would be good to know from marko.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ Yes, I know, but I think my explanation is more explanatory of what is actually happening and avoids unnecessary comments from marko and going straight to the point.

Comment: It seems like it's only on my application. I have a other application and artisan there seems to work fine. Can you see any log messages on that on my application?

Comment: ... like I said... unnecessary comments because all we already know it was not a "suddenly and unexplainable error from artisan"

Comment: If you are more elaborate on the error message maybe we can help you. But it's quite possible that the HTTP_HOST is not set in $_SERVER. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910541/is-the-http-host-server-variable-always-defined

Comment: HTTP_ variables aren't set when you use php cli. It looks like you use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` somewhere in your project without checking if it exists.

Comment: After some debugging I discovered that the .env file is merged into the $_SERVER so I specified it in the .env file instead - HTTP_HOST=localhost:8080. I think the error is something on my windows set-up, maybe CGI, host or some other shit. I really don't know.

Comment: I used the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in a function I created so it was that which was the problem. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @Amarnasan I just came back and agree with your last comment to me regarding your explanation, therefore I give you my thump up to your explanation. have a nice day.

Comment: @marko is this question solved?

Comment: I don't remember anymore. Maybe close this?